# Capturing optional string using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse strings which have this pattern

```
src [interface_name:source_address[/source_port]]
```

where the parts in the brackets are optional. So there are 3 possible variants

```
src
src LAN:10.115.1.204
src LAN:10.115.1.204/8080
```

I want to capture the **interface**, **source ip** and **source port** from this string.

My regex for third variant is

```
($srcinterface,$srcip,$src_port) = m/^src (.*?):(.*?)\/(.*?)/;
```

But I don't know how to make a regex that works for all 3 variants.

**EDIT**
The bigger part of the problem is that like src dst information is also being received from the system and I need to repeat the regex. See below Strings:-

```
src dst outside:125.22.32.192
src outside:182.201.183.178 dst outside:125.22.32.192
src outside:182.201.183.178/5525 dst outside:125.22.32.192/8595
```

Comment: And what do you need exactly to capture in this new example? Please, can you give all fields you need for the second line?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte on second line I need `srcinterface, srcip, dstinterface and dstip` ... there values should be `srsinterface=outside, srcip=182.201.183.178, dstinterface=outside and dstip=125.22.32.192` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead:

```
/^src(?> (\w++):((?>[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(?>\/([0-9]++))?)?/
```

an example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $str = "src
src LAN:10.115.1.204
src LAN:10.115.1.204/8080";
my $i = 0;
while($str =~ /^src(?> (\w++):((?>[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(?>\/([0-9]++))?)?/gm) {
print "\n[match " . ++$i . "]"
    . "\nWhole match    : $&"
    . "\nCapture group 1: $1"
    . "\nCapture group 2: $2"
    . "\nCapture group 3: $3\n";
}
```

For a more permissive pattern, you can use this:

```
/^src(?> (\w++):([^\/\n]++)(?>\/([^\n]++))?)?/gm
```

or this:

```
/^src(?> (\w++):([^\/\n]++)(?>\/(\S++))?)?/gm
```

The idea for these pattern is to use negated character classes, for example `[^\/\n]` means *all characters that are not a slash or a newline*. You can easily adapt these classes to your needs adding or removing characters.

Comment: The possessive quantifiers `++` and `(?>...)` are pointless here.

Comment: Borodin: I use them as a good practice since you obtain a most performant pattern. You can get the same result with `(?:..)` and `+` but a little slower.

Comment: I suggest you write a benchmark to compare the two. All you have achieved is the confusion of everybody who doesn't know Perl regular expressions extremely well.

Comment: How can I replace digits with .*? , validation is needed in my case since in each possible situation the input value will be always correct..

Comment: @Amit: You can replace the ip address `(?>[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})` by `[^\/]++` and the last digits `[0-9]++` by `\S++`. Then it will accept any kind of characters

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I did that but it won't work for String types 1 and 2 where / doesn't come in input String.. Please suggest some other way around..

Comment: @Amit: i added an example script which works with your example string. If you have problem with a particular format of string, please add it to your post.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  
Please see my edit in the question. The original regex you suggested in your answer works fine since the String is long (even longer than the edit) I want to shorten the regex.. Please see if we can use the shorter regex suggested by you... In Second case when port number is not coming (i.e. no / ) in String your alternate regex fails

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Perl guru, but maybe this works:

```
($srcinterface,$srcip,$src_port) = m/^src\s*(?:(.*?):(.*?)(?:\/(.*?))?)?/;
```

`?:` should make it a hidden group, `?` at the end of a group makes it optional.

Well, the readability goes haywire...

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which of the fields are optional, but you can simply split on a regular expression to separate what is there.

In this program, the `@fields` array will contain as many fields as are specified. Assuming optional fields disappear from the right (i.e. there can be no source address wihtout an interface name, and no source port without both a name and an address) you can simply count the fields in `@fields` to see which were provided.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

for (
    'src',
    'src LAN:10.115.1.204',
    'src LAN:10.115.1.204/8080') {

    my @fields = split /[\/\s]+/;

    dd \@fields;
}
```

**output**

```
["src"]
["src", "LAN:10.115.1.204"]
["src", "LAN:10.115.1.204", 8080]
```

Comment: fields inside [ ] are optional

Comment: @Amit: That implies that your lines can be just `src` or a complete `src LAN:10.115.1.204/8080`, and anything in between is incorrect. But your example data includes a line that has just *part* of the information present, so this must be wrong.

Comment: please see the question for the possible values of input string

Comment: Ah, so you cannot have an interface name without a source address? That is written as **src [interface_name:source_address[/source_port]]**. I have modified my answer. You will get one, two, or three elements in the `@fields` array.

Comment: I don't want to use that in a program. I want a regex which can be simply passed to any module which accepts these strings and strings will be parsed using this regex.

Comment: I believe that is shortsighted. A regex will *always* return as many captures as there are parenthesis pairs, it will simply return an empty string for parts that didn't exist. It would be much more flexible to pass a reference to a subroutine, then data of any sort can be processed. I hope you're not planning to read the regex from a file?

Comment: Yes @Borodin I am not reading from a file.. Instead I am trying to parse logs (SYSLOGS) coming from a cisco switch and the above String is just a part of the full log.

Answer (score 1):

This regex worked for me

```
($srcinterface, $srcip, $src_port) = m@^src (?:([^:]+):([^/]+))?(?(1)(?:/(.+))?)@;
```

Notes:

- I'm using negated character class (e.g. `[^:]`) and `+` because the `.*?` would cause trouble for variants 2 and 3 due to the fact that the regex following `.*?` is not well defined (simply put, `.*?` would match a zero-length string).
- I made the **interface_name:source_address** part optional with an enclosing `(?:...)?`
- Then I used the conditional regex `(?(1)pattern)` which means “match `pattern` if capture group 1 is matched successfully”

  Effectively, if **interface_name:source_address** is matched, look for **/port**
- Since **/port** is optional, I wrapped the part in another `(?:...)?` *inside* the conditional regex.

For what it's worth, I think [Borodin's split-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17742849/1743811) is *way* simpler and [Casimir et Hippolyte's regex-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17742634/1743811) is better in terms of robustness since it actually validates each component. I'm just posting this for the sake of completion.